# Sequence of measurable functions $f_n$ on $\mathbb R^n$ converges to $0$ in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am having problems on how to start, any hints are appreciated. Thank you.

> Show that a sequence of measurable functions $f_n$ on $\mathbb R^n$
>   converges to $0$ in measure if and only if 
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\int \frac{|f_n|}{1+|f_n|}\right)=0.
> $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** apply Markov's inequality.  For any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, we have
$$
\int \frac{|f_n|}{1 + |f_n|} \geq 
\epsilon\cdot \mu\left\{ \frac{|f_n|}{1 + |f_n|} \geq \epsilon\right\}
$$
Noting that
$$
\frac{|f_n|}{1 + |f_n|} \geq \epsilon \iff |f_n| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}
$$

Comment: never heard of it before, is it the same as Chebyshev's inequality. thank you.

Comment: I think so.  The term [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality#Corollary:_Chebyshev.27s_inequality) is sometimes reserved for a more specific application.